# How do I remove the characters?

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

How do I remove special characters and alphabets in a string ?

```
 qwert1234*90)!  ' this might be my cell value
```

I have to convert it to

```
 123490  ' I mean I have to remove everything but keep only the numbers in string
```

but it should allow spaces !

```
 qwe123 4567*. 90  ' String with spaces
 123 4567 90     ' output should be
```

I found the [vba](/questions/tagged/vba) `Replace` - but writing a replace for each character makes my code big. Well let me tell you clearly without hiding anything from you:

1. input: `qwe123 4567*. 90`          ' String with spaces  cells(1,"A").value
2. My idea to do these next:  `123 4567 90` ' remove characters first keeping white spaces
3. final output  in `A1:A3`

> 123
>    4567
>    90     
>   
>   *(for every space it should insert row and fill that)*

Could you tell me how do remove all characters except numbers and spaces in string?

Thanks In advance

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to use a regular expression.

See this example:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Test()
    Const strTest As String = "qwerty123 456 uiops"
    MsgBox RE6(strTest)
End Sub

Function RE6(strData As String) As String
    Dim RE As Object, REMatches As Object

    Set RE = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
    With RE
        .MultiLine = False
        .Global = True
        .IgnoreCase = True
        .Pattern = "([0-9]| )+"   
    End With

    Set REMatches = RE.Execute(strData)
    RE6 = REMatches(0)

End Function
```

**Explanation:**
`Pattern = "([0-9]| )+"` will match any 0 or more group (`+`) containing a number (`[0-9]`) or (`|`) a space ().

**Some more info** on the regexp:

- [a thread on ozgrid](http://www.ozgrid.com/forum/showthread.php?t=37624&page=1)
- [a very good reference about regexp](http://www.regular-expressions.info)

Comment: How can this be the accepted answer? It doesn't even work with the example strings the OP provided.

Comment: it works on the example I gave and if it was accepted, it probably works for the OP. Actually, the `.` and `*` make the RE to stop so if you wanted to avoid this, you could add a `replace` before executing the RE

Comment: `Global` should be True.

Comment: @jmax pls see comment above re `Global`

Answer (score 9):

Non-re alternative;

```
Public Function fmt(sValue As String) As String
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 1 To Len(sValue) '//loop each char
        Select Case Mid$(sValue, i, 1) '//examine current char
            Case "0" To "9", " " '//permitted chars
               '//ok
            Case Else
               Mid$(sValue, i, 1) = "!" '//overwrite char in-place with "!"
        End Select
    Next
    fmt = Replace$(sValue, "!", "") '//strip invalids & return
End Function
```

For:

```
?fmt("qwe123 4567*. 90") 
123 4567 90
```

Comment: strips the unwanted characters (nice work with the LHS MID), but doesnt go to the next step to place the sub-strings into descending cells

Answer (score 4):

Those two funny codes will do both of your whishes..

```
Sub MySplitter(strInput As String)
    Row = 10  ' Start row
    Col = "A" ' Column Letter
    Range(Col & Row) = ""   ' Clean the start cell
    For i = 1 To Len(strInput)  ' Do with each Character in input string...
        c = Mid(strInput, i, 1) ' Get actual char
        If IsNumeric(c) Then Range(Col & Row) = Range(Col & Row) & c ' If numeric then append to actual cell
        If (c = " ") And (Range(Col & Row) <> "") Then 'If space and actual row is not empty then...
            Row = Row + 1           ' Jump to next row
            Range(Col & Row) = ""   ' Clean the new cell
        End If
    Next
End Sub

Function KeepNumbersAndSpaces(ByVal strInput As String)
    For i = 1 To Len(strInput)  ' Do with each Character in input string...
        c = Mid(strInput, i, 1) ' Get actual char
        If IsNumeric(c) Or c = " " Then ' If numeric or a space then append to output
            KeepNumbersAndSpaces = KeepNumbersAndSpaces & c
        End If
    Next
End Function

Sub Test()
    strInput = "qwert1234*90)! qwe123 4567*. 90"
    MySplitter (strInput)
    Range("A5") = KeepNumbersAndSpaces(strInput)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

Something like this to

- split the string using a [regexp](/questions/tagged/regexp)
- place the matches into an array
- dump the array to an automatically sized spreadsheet range

*main sub*

```
Sub CleanStr()
Dim strOut As String
Dim Arr
strOut = Trim(KillChar("qwe123 4567*. 90 "))
Arr = Split(strOut, Chr(32))
[a1].Resize(UBound(Arr) + 1, 1) = Application.Transpose(Arr)
End Sub
```

*function*

```
Function KillChar(strIn As String) As String
Dim objRegex As Object
Set objRegex = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
    With objRegex
        .Global = True
        .Pattern = "[^\d\s]+"
        KillChar = .Replace(strIn, vbNullString)
    End With
End Function
```