# Removing all text from inputbox?

Tags: vba, excel

How can I remove all characters from inputbox, leaving just numbers?

I have a macro that runs down a column removing white space, shortening to 13 digits but I also need it to remove any text characters.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7384029/how-do-i-remove-the-characters

Comment: As stupid as this sounds, I actually managed to get this to work really simply a while back, and it wasn't anything nearly as complex as what you've linked (I did it in one line of code). But I can't now remember how I did it and can't find the other project. So thanks for the link but can you leave the question open as this isn't the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I still think a `regexp` is the way to go.

```
Function removeAlpha(strData As String) As String

    strData = Replace(strData, " ", "")

    With CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
        .Pattern = "[A-Za-z]"
        .Global = True
         removeAlpha = .Replace(strData, "")
    End With

End Function
```

And to test:

```
Sub TestClean()
    Const strTest As String = "qwerty123 456 uiops"
    MsgBox removeAlpha(strTest)
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I'll have a look into it some more, although at the moment I can't get it to work. I'll make another question though, since it's a different topic.

Answer (score 0):

An alternate method to using a `regular expression` is:

```
Public Sub removeCharacters()

    For Each RANGE_UNASSIGNED In Worksheets(1).Range("A1:A" & Worksheets(1).Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row)
    STRING_OUTPUT = ""
        For INTEGER_STEP = 1 To Len(RANGE_UNASSIGNED.Value)
            STRING_TEMPORARY = Mid(RANGE_UNASSIGNED.Value, INTEGER_STEP, 1)
                If STRING_TEMPORARY Like "[a-z.]" Or STRING_TEMPORARY Like "[A-Z.]" Then
                    STRING_xOUTPUT = ""
                Else
                    STRING_xOUTPUT = STRING_TEMPORARY
                End If
                STRING_OUTPUT = STRING_OUTPUT & STRING_xOUTPUT
        Next INTEGER_STEP
        RANGE_UNASSIGNED.Value = STRING_OUTPUT
    Next RANGE_UNASSIGNED
End Sub
```

This should remove all alpha characters from your cell(s). You can remove additional characters if required.

Answer (score 0):

An approach based on IsNumeric.

```
Sub Keep_If_IsNumeric()

For j = 1 To Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

Set c = Cells(j, 1)

strc = ""

For i = 1 To Len(c.Value)

n = Mid(c.Value, i, 1)

 If Not IsNumeric(strc & n & "0") Then

   Else

   strc = strc & n

 End If

Next
c.Offset(, 1) = strc
c.Offset(, 2) = Val(Replace(strc, ",", "."))

Next
End Sub
```